# Carrier of a mixed strategy in a 3x3 bimatrix game

Tags: game-theory

We are given a bimatrix game (A,B) = $\begin{bmatrix}0,4 & 4,0 & 5,3\\4,0 & 0,4 & 5,3\\ 3,5 & 3,5  & 6,6 \end{bmatrix}$. Suppose (**p**, **q**) is a Nash equilibrium in (A,B). Prove that {1,2} $\not\subseteq$ C(**p**), where C(**p**) denotes the carrier of the strategy **p**.

To solve this problem I was planning on using the following Corollary:

"A strategy pair (**p**, **q**) is a Nash equilibrium in a bimatrix game (A,B) if and only if C(**p**) $\subseteq$ P$B_1$(**q**) and C(**q**) $\subseteq$ P$B_2$(**p**)".

Now, suppose that {1,2} $\subseteq$ C(**p**). Since C(**p**) $\subseteq$ P$B_1$(**q**) we also have {1,2} $\subseteq$ P$B_1$(**q**) i.e. e$^{1}$**Aq** = max k e$^{k}$**Aq** and e$^{2}$**Aq** = max k e$^{k}$**Aq**. We calculate  e$^{k}$**Aq** for k = 1,2,3. Suppose **q** = (q$_1$, q$_2$, 1 - q$_1$ - q$_2$).

e$^{1}$**Aq** = 5 - 5q$_1$ - q$_2$
e$^{2}$**Aq** = 5 - 5q$_2$ - q$_1$
e$^{2}$**Aq** = 6 - 3q$_2$ - 3q$_1$

We see that {1,2} $\subseteq$ C(**p**) if 5 - 5q$_1$ - q$_2$ = 5 - 5q$_2$ - q$_1$ (so if q$_1$ = q$_2$) and 5 - 5q$_1$ - q$_2$ $\geq$ 6 - 3q$_2$ - 3q$_1$ and 5 - 5q$_2$ - q$_1$   $\geq$ 6 - 3q$_2$ - 3q$_1$ . Substitute q$_1$ = q$_2$ into the second or third inequality to obtain 5 $\geq$ 6 which is ofcourse impossible. We conclude that {1,2} $\not\subseteq$ C(**p**).

Can anyone tell me if my solution is right or not? Thanks in advance! :)